# Superfluid dispersion relation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dispersion, superfluidity

So I have derived that the action of the superfluid is

$$ S_{\text{eff}} = \int d \tau d^d r \left ( \frac{(\partial_{\tau} \theta)^2}{2g} + \frac{1}{2m} \rho_0 (\nabla \theta)^2 \right ) $$

And we should get the dispersion relation. I think this is equivalent to get the equation of motion

$$\ddot{\theta} g^{-1} + m^{-1} \rho_0 \nabla^2 \theta = 0$$

And Fourier transforming

$$E^2 g^{-1} + m^{-1} \rho_0 p^2 = 0$$

But, the problem is immediate. This implies a complex energy, which is obviously wrong. Where is my error? Is there another way to get the dispersion relation?

Comment: $\tau$ is the  Euclidean time or real? It seems that you have to do Wick rotation, which gives you additional minus sign in time derivative. Then you expand in Fourier modes and obtain $-\omega_k^2/g+\rho_0k^2/m$, which gives $\omega_k^2=\rho_0k^2/m$.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov I was being a little sloppy, actually is $\int d \tau d^d r$ instead of $\int dV$, so if we Wick rotate it, the action becomes complex, isn't it a problem?

Comment: When you deal with Euclidean time, you deal with Matsubara frequencies, not real frequencies. To obtain the dispersion law, you need real frequencies. When you do Wick rotation, you change mesure, $dt=-id\tau$ and change sign at time derivative in the action. I do not understand properly what do you mean